# Ejemplo de cajero, no me funciona las funciones de depositar y retirar

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Soy muy nueva en todo esto de html y javaScript, Me gusta muecho :). Sin embargo en este ejemplo tengo problemas en correr las funciones. Me encantaría y estaría super agradecida de la ayuda que me puedan brindar. Saludos

```html
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function cuentasUsuario() {
     var cuenta = document.getElementById("cuenta"),
            saldoActual = document.getElementById("saldoActual");
      saldoActual.value = cuenta.value;
}


      function depositarDinero() {
          var deposito = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("depositar")[0].value);
              saldoActual = saldoActual+deposito;
    alert("Usted es acreedor de un monto de:" +saldoActual);
    }


    function retirarDinero() {
        var retiro = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("retirar")[0].value);  
            if (retiro > saldoActual) {
               alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente (nulo): "+saldoActual);
      } else {
        saldo = saldoActual-retiro;
      }
    }

    function verificarSaldo() {
      document.getElementsByName("verificar")[0].value = saldoActual;

    }


</script>



<form>

Seleccione el nombre y numero de cuenta:

<select id="cuenta" onchange="cuentasUsuario()">
                <option  value="0"></option>
                <option  value="20"> usuario1 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="0">usuario2 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="200"> usuario3 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="1000">usuario4 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
</select>


    <p> Su cuenta actual es: <input type="text"  id="saldoActual"  size="20"></p>


 <form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito">
    <button type="button"    onclick="depositarDinero()">Depositar</button>
      </br>
    </br>   


    <input type="text" name="retirar">
    <button type="button" onclick="retirarDinero()">Retirar</button>
  </form>



    Su saldo actual es</br>
    <input type="text" name="verificar">
    <button type="button"   onclick="verificarSaldo()">Verificar</button>
    </br>
    </br>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?, te recomiendo aprender a depurar tu codigo, coloca unas impresiones y verifica que variables tienen valores inadecuados segun tu logica. :P

Comment: El problema es que cuando le digito el monto en cualquiera de los campos ya sea depositar o retirar y presiono los respectivos botones, no me realiza la acción, es decir, no me funciona.   :(

Comment: he publicado una respuesta, y la mayoria son errores tipograficos y de conversion, revisalo y si te funciono marcala como correcta por favor, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el siguiente enlace: [tour]

Comment: Claro, comprendo!! Vi los infinitos errores, y sin duda, mejoraré esos aspectos! Demasiadas Gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un error repitente en tu codigo es que muchas veces utilizas `etiqueta` en vez de `etiqueta.value`, ademas no conviertes el valor a entero cuando vas a hacer una operación matemática.

Otro error es que usas la variable `saldo` pero este no existe, pienso que lo estas confudiendo con `saldoActual`.

Otro error es que estas tratando de obtener la entrada de `deposito` con la palabra `depositar`.

He corregido el código y ya es funcionable:

```html
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function cuentasUsuario() {
     var cuenta = document.getElementById("cuenta"),
     saldoActual = document.getElementById("saldoActual");
     saldoActual.value = cuenta.value;
}


      function depositarDinero() {
          var deposito = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value);
              saldoActual.value = parseInt(saldoActual.value)+deposito;
      alert("Usted es acreedor de un monto de:" +saldoActual.value);
    }


    function retirarDinero() {

        var retiro = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("retirar")[0].value);  
            if (retiro > parseInt(saldoActual.value)) {
               alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente (nulo): "+saldoActual);
      } else {
        saldoActual.value = parseInt(saldoActual.value)-retiro;
      }
    }

    function verificarSaldo() {
       document.getElementsByName("verificar")[0].value = saldoActual.value;

    }


</script>
<form>

Seleccione el nombre y numero de cuenta:

<select id="cuenta" onchange="cuentasUsuario()">
                <option  value="0"></option>
                <option  value="20"> usuario1 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="0">usuario2 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="200"> usuario3 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
                <option  value="1000">usuario4 - cuenta: 4115 5248 8547</option>
</select>


    <p> Su cuenta actual es: <input type="text"  id="saldoActual"  size="20"></p>


 <form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito">
    <button type="button"    onclick="depositarDinero()">Depositar</button>
      </br>
    </br>   


    <input type="text" name="retirar">
    <button type="button" onclick="retirarDinero()">Retirar</button>
  </form>



    Su saldo actual es</br>
    <input type="text" name="verificar">
    <button type="button"   onclick="verificarSaldo()">Verificar</button>
    </br>
    </br>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda! inmensamente agradecida!! Más que el hecho de corregirme; es  el de explicarme, exactamente el fallo y el porqué. :) Saludos!! :)